# sampling data in R based on predefined proportions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the sample data as:

```r
test <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q",
          "r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
```

I want to create 1000 samples of 5 elements each such that all 5 elements are unique and the occurence of each element in the sample of 1000 is according to below proportions:

[image]

I have tried using below code but when I check the percentage of elements, for eg "a", its not as expected

```
  sample_function <- function(){sample(test,5,replace = FALSE, prob = c('0.9',
'0.8','0.45','0.6','0.3','0.05','0.08','0.12','0.79','0.33','0.24','0.1','0.1',
'0.76','0.22','0.2','0.7','0.67','0.35','0.45','0.07','0.11','0.14','0.03','0.02',
'0.05')) }

sample_data <- replicate(1000,sample_function())
sum(sample_data=="a")
```

The output I expect is close to .9. How to achieve this in R?

Sample should have 1000 rows, two rows can have same set of values but all five elements should be unique and satisfy the given proportion (eg "a" should occur APPROX 900 times in whole dataset of 1000. I'm getting numbers which are not near .9, like .45 for alphabet "a")

Comment: They way you've done it looks right, but your expectations are off - when you sample from a dataset there is a random element and you expect to see stochastic effects - if you run this enough times you will approach the ideal proportions but are very unlikely to ever hit them.  Is it absolutely required that you hit the exact proportions?  Because if so, you need a new approach.

Comment: I understand that, the number Im expecting  is not exact proportions but near. for eg for "a" it does not have to be exact .9, but near. I'm getting .4 in my machine

Comment: just ran it with `set.seed(42)` and I get 0.916 - try setting a new seed and re-running.

Comment: Your `prob` vector has character strings rather than numbers (since you have wrapped them in quotes). Isn't _that_ the cause of your error?

Comment: nope, I get no error. setting seed to 42 is giving me 458 as output from sum(sample_data=="a").

Comment: It's worth noting that your draw-5-without-replacement clause will skew the results - badly if there are extremely common options - imagine if "c" is intended to have a 50% representation, but it can never be higher than 20%..

Comment: without replacement is for the 5 values to be different in each trial. c can occur 50% of the time in 1000 rows, but only once in each row when it does occur

Comment: @q74hyu_oi Yes, but with `sum(sample_data=="a")` you are testing total frequency, not per-trial frequency.

Comment: using sum(sample_data=="a")  is not getting the desired result. without replacement ensures that each set of 5 values are different. replicate function simply repeats this 1000 times. Each repetition of drawing 5 sample is independent of each other.

Comment: @q74hyu_oi that expectation is incorrect.  The method you have described will not lead to a 20% frequency object appearing in 20% of rows.

Comment: I have added an explanation to my answer to avoid extending this in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Testing this, it seems to be working?

```
set.seed(42)
# for reproducibility

test <- letters[1:26] # easier than typing them out
freqs <- as.numeric(c('0.9','0.8','0.45','0.6','0.3','0.05','0.08','0.12','0.79','0.33','0.24','0.1','0.1','0.76','0.22','0.2','0.7','0.67','0.35','0.45','0.07','0.11','0.14','0.03','0.02',
                      '0.05')) 
# these should be numbers so don't need quoting - I just copied your typed vector and applied as.numeric()

sample_function <- function(){sample(test,5,replace = FALSE, prob = freqs) }

expectedFreqs = freqs/sum(freqs)
# normalised frequencies

sample_data <- replicate(1000,sample_function())

df <- data.frame(x = (table(sample_data)/length(sample_data)),
       y = expectedFreqs)
# summarising results

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x.Freq, y=y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
#plot
```

gives
[image]

It's worth noting that your draw-5-without-replacement clause will skew the results - badly if there are extremely common options - imagine if "c" is intended to have a 50% representation, but it can never be higher than 20%

You will see lower-than-expected frequencies for the most frequent options and higher-than-expected for midtable ones as a consequence.
Here's the same seed with 1 million reps:

[image]

### Incorrect expectation

There is discussion in the comments about an expectation that the frequency of the letter "should" lead to that same frequency if we count matches per-trial (a 10% chance letter "should" arise in 10% of sets)

To expand on why the expectation is incorrect:

Consider a simplified case where replacement is allowed.
We want to test a letter "a" with a 10% expected draw rate.

Drawing a letter has a `0.1` probability of drawing "a" and therefore a `1-0.1 = 0.9` probability of drawing non-a.

The chance of drawing your item in a 5-draw set is:

```
0.1 (first draw)
+ 0.9*0.1 (second draw)
+ 0.9*0.9*0.1 (third draw)
+ 0.9*0.9*0.9*0.1 (fourth draw)
+ 0.9*0.9*0.9*0.9*0.1 (fifth draw).
```

Or, more simply
`1 - 0.9^5 = 0.40951`

Now if we include the no-duplicates-in-a-set-of-5 rule it gets worse:
If we don't draw the a first, then we have an increased chance of drawing it next (since one of the alternatives is removed from the pool):
And each time we draw it gets less easily predictable, as the next draw probability is dependent on all previous draws:

```
0.1 (first draw)
+ 0.9*[>0.1]
+ 0.9*(1-[>0.1])*[>>0.1] etc...
```

See here for more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution